# What is the least possible radius for graph built on 100 vertices with maximal degree equals to 4

Tags: graph-theory

So, what I did is I wrote a definition of radius. $R = \min\;\epsilon(x)$, $x \in V(x)$. By $\epsilon(x)$ I mean eccentricity of vertex $x$. So, to minimize radius we, obviously, want to minimize minimal eccentricity. After that in order to translate it to even more easier terms let us write its definition.

$$\epsilon(x) = \max d(x, y), \;\;y \in V(x)$$

So, in order to minimize the least eccentricity we should minimize maximal distance from vertex $x$ to any other vertex.

Can you, please, suggest your ideas for continuation of this proof?

Comment: $$1+4+4\cdot3+4\cdot3^2\lt100\lt1+4+4\cdot3+4\cdot3^2+4\cdot3^3$$

Comment: In a graph with max degree $4$, how hany vertices can be within a distance of $1$ from a vertex $x$? How many can be within a distance of $2$ from $x$? How many can be within a distance of $3$ from $x$? . . .

Comment: @bof could you, please, explain your idea a bit more detailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a graph with maximum degree $\Delta(G)\le4$. Fix a vertex $x$ and define $S_k=\{y:d(x,y)=k\}$. Observe that $|S_0|=1$, $|S_1|\le4$, and for $k\ge1$ we have $|S_{k+1}|\le3|S_k|$; the last inequality because each vertex in $S_k$ (where $k\ge1$) has at least one neighbor in $S_{k-1}$ and at most three neighbors in $S_{k+1}$. It follows that
$$|\{y:d(x,y)\le n\}|=|S_0|+|S_1|+|S_2|+\cdots+|S_n|\le1+4+4\cdot3+\cdot+4\cdot3^{n-1}=2\cdot3^n-1.$$
Since $|\{y:d(x,y)\le3\}|\le1+4+4\cdot3+4\cdot3^2=53$, a graph with maximum degree $4$ and radius $3$ can have no more than $53$ vertices.
Since $1+4+4\cdot3+4\cdot3^2+4\cdot3^3=161$, a graph with maximum degree $4$ and radius $4$ may have as many as $161$ vertices. So the answer to your problem is $4$. We can obviously construct a tree with maximum degree $4$ and radius $4$ which has $161$ vertices, namely $1+4+12+36=53$ vertices of degree $4$ and $108$ leaves. To get a tree with maximum degree $4$, radius $4$, and exactly $100$ vertices, delete $61$ of the leaves.